# pH meter and paraformaldehyde

Tags: ph

We have had an ongoing debate in our lab and several bad pH electrodes. I would like to ask the following question

Do paraformaldehyde soloutions (2-4% w/v) damage pH meter electrodes?

If so, why?

Comment: One would expect that the oligomers block up the membrane in the electrodes. Keeping them in an acidic solution for a while might help, polyformaldehyde degrades to formaline under acidic conditions.